# How to access JSON in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following JSON params.

```
Started POST "/tickets/move.json" for ::1 at 2015-01-30 15:30:13 -0600
Processing by TicketsController#move as JSON
  Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"id"=>"1", "col"=>1, "row"=>1}, {"id"=>"2", "col"=>2, "row"=>2}, {"id"=>"3", "col"=>2, "row"=>1}, {"id"=>"4", "col"=>4, "row"=>1}, {"id"=>"5", "col"=>5, "row"=>1}], "ticket"=>{}}
```

How can I access them, as I would with regular rails params?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a regular `params` hash. Rails is usually smart enough to decode a JSON request and put the resulting object in `params` for you, and the hashrockets (`=>`) are a dead giveaway that it's a Ruby hash and not JSON. Formatted more nicely it looks like this:

```
{ "_json"  => [ { "id" => "1", "col" => 1, "row" => 1 },
                { "id" => "2", "col" => 2, "row" => 2 },
                # ...
              ],
  "ticket" => {}
}
```

You'll access it like any other Hash:

```
p params["_json"]
# => [ {"id"=>"1", "col"=>1, "row"=>1},
#      {"id"=>"2", "col"=>2, "row"=>2},
#      ...
#    ]

p params["_json"][0]
# => {"id"=>"1", "col"=>1, "row"=>1}

p params["_json"][0]["id"]
# => "1"

p params["ticket"]
# => {}
```

It ought to be a HashWithIndifferentAccess, actually, so you should be able to use symbol keys as well:

```
p params[:_json][0][:id]
# => "1"
```

Comment: It is nice that Rails automatically handles the JSON data and maps it into object. `params["_json"]` works perfectly.